# OnFailure/ OnSuccess is not called on ajax form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, ajax-forms

I am trying to submit a ajax form and what i want is to display a confirmation message onsuccess and / or onfailure.

But These two functions never called.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Transfer", "Location", null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "updateSuccess",
    OnFailure = "updateFailure"

}, new { @id = "transferForm" }))
{
  // html here
}
<div id="update-message"></div>
<div id="commonMessage"></div>
```

this is script:

```
<script>
function updateSuccess() {
    if ($("#update-message").html() == "True") {
        $('#commonMessage').html("The ownership has been transfered.");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $("#update-message").show();
    }
}
function updateFailure() {
    if ($("#update-message").html() == "False") {
        $('#commonMessage').html("The ownership has NOT been transfered.Error     occured.");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
    }
    else {

    }
}
</script>
```

After the form submission, i can see that it returns True/False and it is displayed in the "update-message" div. But The confirmation never shows up.
even if I use an 'alert' inside the onFailure/onSuccess , the alert doesnt show up.

Any help guys??

EDIT:
The returned message of controller shows up in the div. But No confirmation message shows up.
[image]

Comment: Could you call alert out of if else scope. Is it work this time?

Comment: I mean `updateSuccess(result){if(result==true)}`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
function updateSuccess() {
        $('#commonMessage').html("The ownership has been transfered.");
        $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
}

function updateFailure() {
    $('#commonMessage').html("The ownership has NOT been transfered.Error     occured.");
    $('#commonMessage').delay(400).slideDown(400).delay(4000).slideUp(400);
}
```

Because `div` updated after ajax operations.

**NOTE**: Does not "OnSuccess" mean "action return true" ?  Also, "OnFailure" = "action return false" ?  Why do you use "if statement"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Unfortunately this one doesn't work. The thing is div (update-message) updates, but the confirmation message dont show up. i just see 'False' or 'True' shows up in the div.

Comment: Could you write controller action method?  ("Transfer")

Comment: i tried what you said with no luck. I think the problem is in somewhere else...but there is no more code to show here :(